# ext.js Messagebox button alignment

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way in Ext.js ext-4.2.1, to left-align two buttons in an Ext.MessageBox?

Starting with (which works):

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({ title:'AA', 
    msg: 'BB',
    prompt: true,
    buttonText: {ok:'Proceed', cancel:'STET'},
    fn: function (btn, groupName) {...}
});
```

The documentation of "buttons:" is clearly wrong and does not display buttons, at "ok:'Foo..." (below).

Can "buttons" be used to specify id, name, and other properties of several buttons, and if so, what is a working example?

" buttons Object/Boolean A button config object (e.g., Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL or {ok:'Foo', cancel:'Bar'}),
"

source: http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.MessageBox.html

Comment: [This](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-show) documentation has a better explanation of `buttons`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you want by adding custom buttons to the dialog:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({ title:'AA', 
   msg: 'BB',
   prompt: true,
   fn: function (btn, groupName) {console.log("fn called");}
}).add([{xtype: 'button', text: 'button1'}, {xtype: 'button', text: 'button2'}]);
```

From there, you can do whatever you want to the buttons. I've omitted the handlers in this example, but this should give you a starting place.

Comment: fn: function (btn, groupName)... is never called in this solution.How can I size the buttons and pack them to the left, as MessageBox does- but in the center?